# How can I find the name of a Package?

Tags: apt, package-management, naming

I want to create links to software within Software Center using the APTURL - However, I'm not sure how to find out the true "package name". What is the easiest way to discover a package's name for use with the APTURL or `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the name of a package through the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

Once launched type the name of the software you wish to find the package name for in the top right search box.

[image]

Once you find the software you are looking for select "More Info"

[image]

At the bottom of the additional information page you'll find Version information which contains, in parentheses, the name of the package

[image]

This is the package name you'll want to use in either `apt-get` commands or in APTURL links. Also - as demonstrated in the above picture - the package names of available add-ons are listed in parentheses next to each respective add-on.

Answer (score 12):

You can search for package names using the command line and the `apt-cache` command.  For example, enter the following command to find out what the package name is for "firefox":

```
apt-cache search firefox
```

If you get a long list of results, you can view (pipe) the results in a viewer:

```
apt-cache search firefox | less
```

or a text file:

```
apt-cache search firefox > ~/firefox-list.txt
```

The command `apt-cache search searchstring` performs a full text search over all the software sources registered on your Ubuntu system. It will search the package names and the descriptions for an occurrence of the `searchstring` term and will print out the package name and the short description, including virtual package names.

If `--names-only` is given, then the long description is not searched, only the package name is.  This option usually gives a smaller set of results.

Answer (score 8):

To create an APT link, open up Ubuntu Software Center ( *Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center* ), search for and find a package:

[image]

Now click *Edit -> Copy Web Link* or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]

You should now have an APT link in your clipboard, like this: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/moovida

Answer (score 2):

How about just using:

```
aptitude search <search_terms>
```

And then you will have some info to use.

Comment: the output was much better  than "apt-cache search <package>"
but in my case, I should first install "aptitude" by this command:
sudo apt install aptitude

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt-cache search` to find the package name of a package in the default Ubuntu repositories that is installable by apt. For example search for an Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that has the '455' version number somewhere in its package name (including in the middle of the package name).

```
apt-cache search 455
```

Search for a package with a name that includes '455-generic' (including the hyphen character in the package name).

```
apt-cache search 455-generic
```

Search for a package with a name that starts with 'postgresql-12-'.

```
apt-cache search "^postgresql-12-"
```

The caret character `^` in  `"^postgresql-12-"` indicates that the package name starts with `postgresql-12-`

Search for a package with a name that ends with '455'.

```
apt-cache search 455$
```

The `$` character in  `455$` indicates that the package name ends with `455`

Search for a package with a name that contains both 'docker' and 'client'.

```
apt-cache search docker | grep client
```