# Is there an official website containing a list of all apt packages with descriptions?

Tags: apt, package-management

I wonder is there a website for apt packages similar to https://www.npmjs.com/ where I can read description of all available packages?

I read some manuals how to install some software and it's written there to run `sudo apt install something`, but I have no idea what that `something` is needed for. How can I get that information?

Comment: The question is generic, so you are likely to get generic answers. Sometimes you will find the package descriptions useful to determine what `something` "is needed for"...but sometime you won't.

Comment: I like to install synaptic and then I can search from wtihin it. Once I have learned package names I then later with newer install can use terminal or my install script to update a new install. `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the name of a Package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14649/how-can-i-find-the-name-of-a-package)

Comment: @mook765  no, that question is quite specific. My question is more general, and I wanted to know "how it all works".

Comment: @user535733 you are right - I want generic answers, from which I can get to know about something that I do not suspect about. E.g. I haven't asked about `apt show`, but it seems that the website doesn't contain any descriptions at all, but this command is rather handy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Website

Yes, there is one. http://packages.ubuntu.com

You can search for packages for all supported versions of Ubuntu.
For example, to quickly search for the package `gimp`, you can go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/gimp

### Directly using apt

Alternatively, you can search from the package in `apt` itself.

`apt search something` shows all packages which has `something` in its name and description.

`apt show exact-packagename-of-something` shows all details (description, dependencies, recommended packages, name of the packager) of the package.

### Manual pages

As mentioned in the comment by @codlord, you can go to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ to search for manual pages (user guides) for any package.

Comment: Also, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ for searching manual pages of some packages if you want to see more details or exactly what something does before installing it.